# I want to access the list of all emails of users present in the users collection from the accounts-ui meteor package

Tags: meteor

var user = Meteor.users.find().fetch;
This returns me a as expected but how should i retrieve only the emails.address field for all the users present in the users collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```js
var emails = _.chain(Meteor.users.find().fetch())
  .pluck('emails')
  .flatten()
  .pluck('address')
  .value();
```

That will get you a flat list of emails, however be aware that in meteor users *can* have multiple email addresses (if your UI supports that). With the example above, all of them will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be:

```
db.users.find({},{ "emails.address" : 1});
```

This would produce something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "caGts2niaDyS6TbYJ", "emails" : [ { "address" : "asoldfj@bigglie.com" } ] }
{ "_id" : "g5oPp4ReDCwuuW8yn", "emails" : [ { "address" : "blogsalfd@sag.com" } ] }
{ "_id" : "ge9YyFehBMN7q3xQ9", "emails" : [ { "address" : "hag@toldyou.com" } ] }
```

If you don't want the _id:

```
db.users.find({},{ "emails.address" : 1, "_id": 0});
```

Which produces:

```
{ "emails" : [ { "address" : "asoldfj@bigglie.com" } ] }
{ "emails" : [ { "address" : "blogsalfd@sag.com" } ] }
{ "emails" : [ { "address" : "hag@toldyou.com" } ] }
```

David Weldon rightly points out that the emails address field is actually an array, so that you can hold more than one email in the field.

However you can use it and search it without worrying about the array up to a point if you know it only contains one email. For example the following will produce a single record:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({ "emails.address" : 'asoldfj@bigglie.com' });
```